# centos 6.4 trouble with /dev/pts/ptmx

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, virtualization

I have a problem with the server running on CentOS. CentOS has been upgraded to version 6.4 and has all updates. Updates were made according to the official repositories. On the server running the V-Server.

**/etc/fstab**

```
# Device     Mountpoint   FStype  Options                 Dump Pass
/dev/sda1      /boot      ext3    rw,noatime                1  2
/dev/vg0/root  /          ext3    rw,noatime                1  1
/dev/vg0/swap  none       swap    sw                        0  0
/dev/vg0/usr   /usr       ext3    rw,noatime                1  2
/dev/vg0/var   /var       ext3    rw,noatime                1  2
/dev/vg0/log   /var/log   ext3    rw,noatime                1  2
/dev/vg0/tmp   /tmp       ext3    rw,noatime,nosuid,noexec  1  2
/dev/vg0/home  /home      ext3    rw,noatime                1  2
/dev/vg0/vz    /vservers  ext3    rw,noatime                1  2
tmpfs          /dev/shm   tmpfs   defaults                  0  0
devpts         /dev/pts   devpts  rw,gid=5,mode=620         0  0
sysfs          /sys       sysfs   defaults                  0  0
proc           /proc      proc    defaults                  0  0
```

The problem is with `/dev/pts/ptmx`:

```
root@Hostname #/dev/pts > ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Sep 12 12:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root 3860 Sep 12 12:34 ..
crw--w---- 1 mmichalski tty 136, 0 Sep 12 12:53 0
c--------- 1 root root 5, 2 Sep 12 12:34 ptmx
```

As you can see it has no rights. The same situation is running virtual. Below is the fstab file virtual

fstab on virtual running on Vserver

> none /proc proc defaults 0 0
>   none /tmp tmpfs size=16m,mode=1777 0 0
>   none /dev/pts devpts gid=5,mode=620 0 0

What can cause this problem and where to look for solutions?

Comment: The rights on `/dev/pts/ptmx` are normal. What is your actual problem?

Answer (score 1):

If I read the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/devpts.txt) correctly, this is by design:

```
The only difference between this single-instance mode and the legacy mode
is the presence of new, '/dev/pts/ptmx' node with permissions 0000, which
can safely be ignored.
```